# What is an asynchronous primitive in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, settimeout, setinterval

What exactly is an "asynchronous primitive" in JavaScript?

According to MDN:

"In JavaScript, a primitive (primitive value, primitive data type) is data that is not an object and has no methods. There are 7 primitive data types: string, number, bigint, boolean, null, undefined, symbol (new in ECMAScript 2016)."

How then could an asynchronous method be a primitive? Various articles and blogs refer to methods like settimeout and setinterval as "asynchronous primitives" but I'm not sure how they fit the definition of a primitive.

Comment: I personally wouldn't call them asynchronous primitives. I'd just call them asynchronous functions. The term "asynchronous primitive" is not standard.

Comment: That's a very weird phrasing. `setTimeout` is a function which returns a primitive (an integer). The two words "asynchronous primitive" together do not make much sense. The person who wrote what you read probably just got their terminology messed up.

Comment: Without seeing these various articles and blogs for myself (haven't seen the term "asynchronous primitive" before), my guess is that their intention was to describe "building-blocks of asynchronicity."

Comment: I also believe someond meant a builtin library function you are not able to replicate on your own.

Answer (score 0):

The term "asynchronous primitive" is not defined in any standard. As such the meaning of the term depends on who you ask.

I personally would not use the term but would understand what someone means by it. It simply means an asynchronous function that was implemented in C.